# Filter a String in android

Tags: android, string

```
String test = "{helloworld=Text to be filtered}";
```

I need to get "Text to be filtered" from the above string.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. I have no idea. Please help.

Comment: I'm feeling confused. Please help.

Comment: After JSON parsing, I listed the items in ListView. On getting the item value, I get this type of string : "{helloworld=Text to be filtered}". So I needed to get the "Text to be filtered".

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of String.split() method in this case.

```
String test = "{helloworld=Text to be filtered}";
String testAfterSplit[] = test.split("=");
```

`testAfterSplit[0]` will be holding the value "**{helloworld**" and
  `testAfterSplit[1]` will be holding the value "**Text to be filtered}**"

you can read more about split [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

Comment: I got the answer myself !

String test = "{helloworld=Text to be filtered}";
String test2 = test.replace("{helloworld=","");
String test3 = test2.replace("}","");

Now I can use test3 string :D That's all I found myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf method. It retruns the position of character you want. In this case:

```
int pos = text.IndexOf("=");
String filter = text.substring(pos, text.length());
```

It returns an string from position of = to the end.